# Subscribe to any bubbled-up WPF child control routed event without an instance of a child control

Tags: wpf, routed-events

I've got a WPF Custom control containing a canvas showing multiple child objects and (possibly) `ItemsControl`s.  I have no idea how many child objects there will be or how nested they will be.

But I need this control to catch any "bubbled-up" `Thumb.DragCompleted` events from any child `Thumb`.  The problem is, it does not have any particular instance of a `Thumb` control to subscribe to.  It just needs to catch the event regardless and take a certain action if the thumb meets certain criteria.

Is it possible to subscribe to all such child events in code-behind?   The closest I can see appears to be `EventManager.RegisterClassHandler` but I don't want a `DragCompleted` for every thumb in the application, just the ones for my child objects.  I must be missing some obvious function, yes?

The examples I find seem to expect that you actually have a `Thumb` control object instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to a bubbling-type routed event in XAML like so:

```
<Grid Name="ParentGrid" Thumb.DragCompleted="DragCompletedEventHandler">
    <!--Some children possibly containing a Thumb-->
</Grid>
```

In the above example, any `Thumb` inside `ParentGrid` that raises its `DragCompleted` event will eventually call `DragCompletedEventHandler` (provided another handler deeper in the tree does not get called first and set `RoutedEventArgs.Handled` to `True`, which would stop the propagation).

You can accomplish the same thing in code like this:

```
ParentGrid.AddHandler(Thumb.DragCompletedEvent, new DragCompletedEventHandler(DragCompletedEventHandler));
```

Where `ParentGrid` is the parent control at the level at which you want to listen.